# SQL Server 2017 evaluated a piece of code that should never be evaluated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select * 
from fb_lab_test 
where (report_item_code = 'HBcAb') 
   or (report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
       case isnumeric(result) when 1 then cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2)
```

> Error converting data type varchar to float

Here is sample data

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE fb_lab_test
(
    [id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Test_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [execute_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [PatientId] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Visit_Id] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Patient_Type] [int] NULL,
    [PatientName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [result_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [report_item_name] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [report_item_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [result] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO fb_lab_test 
VALUES ('5910315197','2019-10-31 00:40:53.000','111111','1','1','Tom','2019-10-31 08:56:54.000','test1','KET','-')
```

In this sample data,`isnumeric` will return false positives,but `case isnumeric(result) when 1 then cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2` should never be evaluated,cause in the sample date there is no `report_item_code` named 'Anti-Hbc',that's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (using your data) an error is not thrown. Sometimes, the engine decides to perform operations in advance (in order to optimize a particular query). I believe, you are getting an error because of this behavior.

You can fix it using `TRY_CAST`:

```
select * from fb_lab_test 
where (report_item_code = 'HBcAb') 
or (
    report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
    case isnumeric(result) when 1 then try_cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually behaving per the documentation ...

ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

SQL Server returns an error message when converting nonnumeric char, nchar, nvarchar, or varchar data to decimal, float, int, numeric. SQL Server also returns an error when an empty string (" ") is converted to numeric or decimal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If you need to convert it in a single expression, I suggest you use a money type which supports up to 4 decimal places. Otherwise you have to deal with the 'possible' number values of `+` `-` `.` etc...

Comment: I have replace the `ISNUMERIC(result) ` with `PATINDEX('%[^0-9|.]%',result)`,but  it's not the point of the issue,cause `case isnumeric(result) when 1 then cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2` should never be evaluated in the sample data I give ,anyway thanks a lot

Comment: `case isnumeric(result)` when result is `-` returns 1 which is why the CAST is being called. The SQL Server Documentation calls it out as such. The sample data you gave has a result of `-`.

Comment: But in my sample data there is no report_item_code named 'Anti-Hbc'...sorry for my poor English and unclear expression

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `isnumeric()` at all.  Just use the `try_` functions:

```
select t.* 
from fb_lab_test t
where report_item_code = 'HBcAb'  or
      (report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
       coalesce(try_cast(float_result), 10000.0) > 0.2
      );
```

It is also a good idea to avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  They basically short-circuit the optimizer.

In this case, you want to include the non-numeric values.  More commonly, these would be excluded.  You can just let the `NULL` comparison exclude them.  That logic would be:

```
select t.* 
from fb_lab_test t
where report_item_code = 'HBcAb'  or
      (report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
       try_cast(float_result) > 0.2   -- excludes non-NULL values
      );
```